# How can I view an entire article on websites that require login for you to see it?

Tags: web, text, view, inspect, article

I'm wondering how can I view the entire text of an article on the web (e.x. The Economist web page), for which you need subscription to be able to see it in full.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by copying the url to the following page textise.net which extracts the entire body and formats is in a cool text-only way.